# WordPress custom post between every five posts

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: custom post]

I'm trying to figure out how in the best way to accomplish what the image show.
I've been trying with modulus to do a if/else, but since the custom post is also a post there will be duplicates. I'm thinking about creating 2 custom queries, one with all the ordinary posts and one with the custom post, but that will make it slower and it doesn't seem like a good solution..

Here's the code of home.php in the wp-content\themes\theme\home.php

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div id="posts" <?php hive_blog_class( 'archive__grid  grid  masonry' ); ?>>
            <?php /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile; ?>
        </div>

        <?php hive_paging_nav();
    else :
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
    endif; ?>

</div><!-- #main -->
```

Comment: Do you know the number of posts that will show on the page? Is it fixed? Or is this like a dynamic scrolling thing where they keep loading?

Comment: @JeremyHarris It's dynamic/infinite scroll!

Comment: Maybe in the session keep an array of post ID's you've loaded. And then on each query, include a `WHERE id NOT IN (...)` type thing to exclude already shown ones.

Comment: @JeremyHarris Good idea! I will give it a try and return with results!

Comment: Idea: You create a variable i and for each iteration you say i++. Then you create something like if (is_integer( $i/5 )== 1){ // custom post here}